# wired connection 1 connection established" but still there is no internet

Tags: internet-connection

This is the glorious day, i stated using Ubuntu with 12.10. I am using connection for internet. when connected wire in my laptop. It saying "**wired connection 1 connection established" but still there is no internet**.when i was using windows 8. windows asked for username and password that is given my service provider. but when i click on connection information. its show connection information. such as

General

1. interface Ethernet(eth0)
2. Hardware Address:..............;
3. Driver : e100
4. speed:....
5. security :...

Ipv4

1.IP Address:.............

1. Broadcast Address:......
2. Subnet Mark:............
3. Defult Route:...........
4. Primary DNS.............
5. Secondary DNS:..........

Ipv6

I am using hp pavilion dv6000,

Answer (score 0):

Go to networking icon (up and down arrows near the menu you use to shutdown) and click on edit connections. Use the appropriate type of connection (sounds like dsl??) and enter username and password by clicking on the connection and hitting the edit button.